# About segmentation fault

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I'm trying to do some kind of voip application using UDP.I have added RSA algorithm for safety.However its gives and segmentation fault.

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <linux/soundcard.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define LENGTH 3    /* how many seconds of speech to store */
#define RATE 8000   /* the sampling rate */
#define FILE_INPUT "/dev/dsp" /* Path to the sound card. */
#define FILE_OUTPUT "/dev/dsp"


/*-RSA-*/
//Her is gcd function
int gcd(int a,int b)
{
    while(a!=b){

        if(a>b)
            a-=b;
        else
            b-=a;
    }
    return a;
}


//This is called  Extended Euclid’s Algorithm to find d.

int findD(int e,int n)
{

    int f=e;
    int d=n;

    int x1, x2, x3, y1, y2, y3;
    x1 = 1; x2 = 0; x3 = f; //p
    y1 = 0; y2 = 1; y3 = d; //d



    int q = 0, i = 1;
    int t1 = 0, t2 = 0, t3 = 0;
    do
    {
        if (i == 1)
        {
            q = x3 / y3;
            t1 = x1 - (q * y1);
            t2 = x2 - (q * y2);
            t3 = x3 - (q * y3);
        }
        else
        {
            x1 = y1; x2 = y2; x3 = y3;
            y1 = t1; y2 = t2; y3 = t3;
            q = x3 / y3;
            t1 = x1 - (q * y1);
            t2 = x2 - (q * y2);
            t3 = x3 - (q * y3);
        }
        i++;


        if (y3 == 0)
        {
            break;
        }

    } while (y3 != 1);

    if (y3 == 0)
    {
        //printf("Sayinin tersi yoktur!!!!");
    }
    else
    {
        // printf("\nSayinin tersi : %d" , y2);
    }

    if(y2<=0)
    {

        y2=e+y2;

    }
    return y2;

}

//Instead of using pow function,I have choose to write square and multiply method which is faster and
//more suitable for big integers.Because we have no such a change to find 104^30 such like that
//Here computes pow(a,b)%n
int squareMul(int a,int b,int n)
{

    int y = 1;

    /*  Compute pow(a, b) % n using the binary square and multiply method. */
    while (b != 0)
    {
        /*  For each 1 in b, accumulate y. */
        if (b & 1)
        {
            y = (y * a) % n;
        }

        /* Square a for each bit in b. */
        a = (a * a) % n;

        /*  Prepare for the next bit in b. */
        b = b >> 1;
    }

    return y;

}
//Encyrption function
//Assume our plain-text is M
int *encyrpt(int text[],int e,int n)
{

    int t=0;
    int *s=(int *)malloc(100);

    for(t=0;t<sizeof(text);t++)
    {
        int gec=(int)text[t];

        //Here computes E(M)=M^e mod n;
        s[t]=squareMul(gec,e,n);

    }


    return s;


}

//Here is decyrption
//Assume our chipher-text is C
int *decyrpt(int enc[],int d,int e,int n)
{
    int i=0;
    int *s=(int *)malloc(100);

    for(i=0;i<sizeof(enc);i++)
    {
        int gelenEnc=(int)enc[i];
        //Here computes D(C)=C^d mod n;
        s[i]=squareMul(gelenEnc,d,n);


    }
    return s;

}



//Here is totient function to find prime to  m.
int totient(int m)
{

    int i;
    int ph=1;
    for(i=2;i<m;i++){

        if(gcd(i,m)==1)
        {
            ph=i;
            break;

        }
    }
    return ph;

}
/*-RSA-*/


int main()
{
    int sock,bytes_recv;
    struct sockaddr_in server_addr;
    struct hostent *host;
    char send_data[LENGTH*RATE];
    char recv_data[LENGTH*RATE];
    int addr_len, bytes_read;
    struct client_addr;


    /* this buffer holds the digitized audio */
    unsigned char buf[LENGTH*RATE];

    /*----------RSA-----------------------*/    

    //Here are some variables that I used for RSA ALGORİTHM
    //str is our plain-text
    char *plainText;
    int *ascii;
    int *enc;
    int *dec;
    int p,q;
    int k=0;
    int n;
    int e;
    int c;
    int phi;
    int d;

    plainText="Merhaba";

    //Here enter 2 relatively prime number
    //I have chose the p=73 and q=151

    p=73;
    q=151;

    printf("\n\ p :%d and q :%d \t \n",p,q);
    //Here computes n
    n = p*q;
    //Here computes phi func simply
    phi=(p-1)*(q-1);

    printf("\n\ n :\t= %d \n",n);
    printf("\n\ Phi :\t= %d \n",phi);

    //Here Euilers Totient function.It finds a number 'e' which is relatively prime with phi.
    e=totient(phi);
    //Here computes d,which is multiplicative inverse of e modula phi.
    d=findD(phi,e);

    printf("\n\ e :\t= %d  \n",e);

    printf("\n\ d :\t= %d which is multiplicative inverse of e modula phi \n",d);


    //Here is the ascii values for plainText.I have created new array in order to store plainText's ascii for simplicty
    ascii=(int *)malloc(sizeof(int)*sizeof(plainText)/sizeof(char));


/*---------------RSA------------*/


    int sound_device;

    /* open sound device */
    //I defined sound card both read and write mode for simplicity
    sound_device = open("/dev/dsp", O_RDWR);
    if (sound_device < 0) {
        perror("Open sound card failed");
        exit(1);
    }


    host= (struct hostent *) gethostbyname((char *)"127.0.0.1");


    if ((sock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0)) == -1)
    {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    server_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.sin_port = htons(5000);
    server_addr.sin_addr = *((struct in_addr *)host->h_addr);
    bzero(&(server_addr.sin_zero),8);


    while(1){

        read(sound_device, buf, sizeof(buf)); /* record some sound */

          printf("\n Size of buff: %d",sizeof(buf));
          ascii=malloc(LENGTH*RATE);
          buf=malloc(LENGTH*RATE);

                  printf("\n Size of ascii: %d",sizeof(ascii));

          //Here ascii stores plaintText's ascii number.
        for(c=0;c<LENGTH*RATE;c++)
        {

        int k=(int)buf[c];

        ascii[c]=k;
        printf("\n\t Ascii's of %c  \t= %d  \n",buf[c],ascii[c]);
            printf("\n\t C: %c  \t= %d  \n",c);
        }

         enc=encyrpt(ascii,e,n);


        //Send function to server
        sendto(sock, enc, LENGTH*RATE, 0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr));

        //Listen from server for 3 seconds
        ioctl(sound_device, SOUND_PCM_SYNC, 0);
        bytes_recv = recvfrom(sock,buf,LENGTH*RATE,0,(struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, &addr_len);

        printf("\n Sended:");
        if(bytes_recv==LENGTH*RATE){

            printf("\nMessage received from server,listen:");
            //Here is decyription
            dec=decyrpt(buf,d,e,n);
            write(sound_device, dec, sizeof(dec));


            ioctl(sound_device, SOUND_PCM_SYNC, 0);
            }
    }

}


 Ascii's of �   = 131  

 C: �   = 10989
```

Segmentation fault

However,my RSA algorithm works properly in other char array separetly.Any idea?
Thanks

Comment: Have you ever heard about a debugger?

Comment: You should use the debugger to determine what line caused the seg fault, and then work backwards from there.

Comment: Your code generates 16 warnings with `gcc -Wall ...` - some of these might be important - you should fix all of them.

Comment: Please don't ship this RSA implementation with the statement that it is secure. There are a number of buffer overflow vulnerabilities that will make people very sad.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Segmentation fault is usually caused by trying to access memory that was not allocated for the process.  This often comes about when you are indexing into arrays (especially, dynamically created ones).

In your code you have a fixed-size `malloc()` in the `encypt()` and `decrypt()` functions, but you access its elements based on the size of the input array, which *could* be a cause for the seg.fault.

To be sure, you will need to use a debugger and see where the over/under indexing occurs.  Be sure to check accessed to other arrays as well (whether dynamically alocated or not)

Also, `sizeof(plainText)` returns the size of a pointer-to-char, not the length of the string.  You will either need to declare `plaintext` as a stack-based array, or use the `strlen()` function.

Answer (score 2):

As people in the comments have pointed out, you should be using a debugger to find out where the segmentation fault is happening exactly.

However, a cursory analysis (which is something a developer should always do, before digging out debuggers) shows a number of pointers that are being used without care.

Any time you make a call to `malloc`, you should be confirming that it was successful. If it wasn't and you try to use the pointer that you `malloc`ed to, you can get a segfault.

You also assign a string to an un`malloc`ed pointer (`plainText`)... BOOM: segfaults, ahoy!

A bunch of your functions do unchecked `malloc`s as well.

So, there are a few places you should look.

Comment: Thanks for answers.I'll try to figure out this problem